# How To Store Values Within JAR \ Java Project

Tags: java, jar, store

I've looked around for this for a while now and haven't really found anything conclusive.

I have a java project that I want to run (Desktop Application) and I wish, upon the first startup, for the user to enter a few values which will remain the values of the respective variables forever, i.e. when I re-run the jar file, the changed values will show instead of the initial packaged values.

I tried using xml to store the file within the jar and read and write to it, no success. So now I've opt to do this.

However if there's a simpler way, please enlighten me, this is one of the initial steps of a bigger project for me and I refuse to go on till I solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only a few values to store, not a large file, then `Preferences` is the solution designed for this.

```
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("/com/yourcompany/yourprogram");

int value = prefs.getInt("key", -1);
if(value == -1) {
   prefs.put("value", Integer.parseInt(
             JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value:"));
   prefs.flush();
}
```

Comment: yes infact i have very few values to store, and indeed they are preferences, you see i wish the app to communicate with a MySQL server, so i want the user to establish a connection using 'server address' and 'server port', those are the only two variables i wish to store within the JAR. so this preferences thing you mentioned, its a class within java?... hmmm, gonna look it up :) thanks

Comment: you guys are stars! thanks everyone! shoo, you know i've been banging my head over this, eventually i just wanted to do it the xml way, but that seemed extremely tedious. you've solved sleepless night problem! :) thanks all you guys for all your help! p.s. didnt even know there was a preferences class. nice one! :) SOLVED!

oh and just in case someone else popps by...
[PREFERENCES TUTORIAL](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/preferences/)

Comment: If we have large amount of data then what we can do?

Answer (score 2):

You should not write inside the JAR. I suggest you store the values user entered somewhere in that user's directory (you can use `System.getProperty("user.home")` to get the path to user directory). Then you can check if the file in user directory exists - if yes, use it, if not, use the one from your JAR that contains defaults (or ask the user to enter the values).

Comment: wow, thanks for the speedy answer.
i'd be lying to you if i told you i hadn't considered it...
the only reason i opted not to do that is to package everything in one file, dislike segregation!

ok, how about this, is it possible to update a variable at runtime,
then once restarted, the variable remains changed?